# MATLAB crashes unexpectedly on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, images, crash, matlab

I'm having difficulties in running a set of experiments due to frequent and unpredictable crashes of MATLAB. I am working on Windows & and I suspected that it was related to plotting graphs. Now, I removed all related functions but the issue persists. Bellow is the latest crash dump:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Fri May 09 13:07:50 2014
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 000000000401a1f0  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000100
  RSP = 000000000401a1c0  RBP = 000000000401b340
  RSI = 000000000401a2c0  RDI = 0000000000000100

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000000100
  R10 = 000000005e154658  R11 = 000000000401a250
  R12 = 0000000072b7dd70  R13 = 0000000000000001
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 000000000401b340

  RIP = 000000005e113270  EFL = 00010246

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x000000005e113270 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\wtifc.mexw64+00078448 mexFunction+00057776
[  1] 0x000000005e1077e7 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\wtifc.mexw64+00030695 mexFunction+00010023
[  2] 0x000000005e109014 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\wtifc.mexw64+00036884 mexFunction+00016212
[  3] 0x000000005e102760 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\wtifc.mexw64+00010080
[  4] 0x000000005e105292 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\wtifc.mexw64+00021138 mexFunction+00000466
[  5] 0x0000000004e1f731        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00063281 mexRunMexFile+00000129
[  6] 0x0000000004e1e202        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00057858 inSwapMexfileReader+00000226
[  7] 0x0000000004e1f2b4        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00062132 _constructor_lm_mexmaci64+00001620
[  8] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[  9] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 10] 0x00000000046a6d48 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00683336 inDestroyWS+00240776
[ 11] 0x00000000046a91ff C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00692735 inDestroyWS+00250175
[ 12] 0x00000000046c021f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
[ 13] 0x00000000046c0370 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
[ 14] 0x000000000469f1dd C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
[ 15] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 16] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 17] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 18] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 19] 0x0000000074ea022f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00131631 mdSearch::mdSearch+00000367
[ 20] 0x0000000074e8e71b  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00059163 mdMxarrayFunctionHandle::isHiddenFunctionBinding+00000491
[ 21] 0x0000000075a66194         C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmx.dll+00287124 mxFevalFunctionHandle+00000036
[ 22] 0x000000000462da0e C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00186894 inFullFevalFcn+00000142
[ 23] 0x0000000074e8cf7f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00053119 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000975
[ 24] 0x0000000074e8cd8f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052623 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000479
[ 25] 0x00000000046a6d48 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00683336 inDestroyWS+00240776
[ 26] 0x00000000046a91ff C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00692735 inDestroyWS+00250175
[ 27] 0x00000000046c021f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
[ 28] 0x00000000046c0370 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
[ 29] 0x000000000469f1dd C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
[ 30] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 31] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 32] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 33] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 34] 0x00000000046cbc7b C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00834683 inDestroyWS+00392123
[ 35] 0x00000000046bb091 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00766097 inDestroyWS+00323537
[ 36] 0x00000000046a008f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00655503 inDestroyWS+00212943
[ 37] 0x00000000046b65a4 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00746916 inDestroyWS+00304356
[ 38] 0x00000000046ac3b0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00705456 inDestroyWS+00262896
[ 39] 0x00000000046a8fe4 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00692196 inDestroyWS+00249636
[ 40] 0x00000000046c021f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
[ 41] 0x00000000046c0370 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
[ 42] 0x000000000469f1dd C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
[ 43] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 44] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 45] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 46] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 47] 0x00000000046cbc7b C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00834683 inDestroyWS+00392123
[ 48] 0x00000000046bb091 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00766097 inDestroyWS+00323537
[ 49] 0x00000000046a008f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00655503 inDestroyWS+00212943
[ 50] 0x00000000046b65a4 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00746916 inDestroyWS+00304356
[ 51] 0x00000000046ac3b0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00705456 inDestroyWS+00262896
[ 52] 0x00000000046a8fe4 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00692196 inDestroyWS+00249636
[ 53] 0x00000000046c021f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
[ 54] 0x00000000046c0370 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
[ 55] 0x000000000469f1dd C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
[ 56] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 57] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 58] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 59] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 60] 0x00000000046cbc7b C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00834683 inDestroyWS+00392123
[ 61] 0x00000000046bb091 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00766097 inDestroyWS+00323537
[ 62] 0x00000000046a008f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00655503 inDestroyWS+00212943
[ 63] 0x00000000046b65a4 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00746916 inDestroyWS+00304356
[ 64] 0x00000000046ac3b0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00705456 inDestroyWS+00262896
[ 65] 0x000000000469f112 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651538 inDestroyWS+00208978
[ 66] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 67] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 68] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 69] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 70] 0x00000000046a6d48 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00683336 inDestroyWS+00240776
[ 71] 0x000000000461f9f7 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00129527 inFullEvalFcn+00022023
[ 72] 0x00000000046aa877 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00698487 inDestroyWS+00255927
[ 73] 0x00000000046c021f C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
[ 74] 0x00000000046c0370 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
[ 75] 0x000000000469f1dd C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
[ 76] 0x00000000046a0bd0 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
[ 77] 0x000000000468cf79 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
[ 78] 0x0000000074e8c64f  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
[ 79] 0x0000000074e8ced2  C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
[ 80] 0x000000000460e70e C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00059150 inValidateLoadedObject+00002350
[ 81] 0x0000000004716495 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01139861 IInterpreter::IInterpreter+00000229
[ 82] 0x000000000471ca45 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01165893 inRegisterFunctionHandles+00004405
[ 83] 0x000000000471ca12 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01165842 inRegisterFunctionHandles+00004354
[ 84] 0x000000000471c9d7 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01165783 inRegisterFunctionHandles+00004295
[ 85] 0x000000000470ba0e C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01096206 inGetSeqVarPtrsFromCurrentWS+00005742
[ 86] 0x000000000460be89 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048777 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000329
[ 87] 0x000000000460bdcc C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048588 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000140
[ 88] 0x000000000460bd81 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048513 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 89] 0x0000000079fbbecd   C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00048845 mnDebugPrompt+00000109
[ 90] 0x0000000079fbd01b   C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00053275 mnParser+00000763
[ 91] 0x000000007499daa4           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00187044 mcrInstance::mnParser_on_interpreter_thread+00000036
[ 92] 0x0000000074982220           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00074272 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00031664
[ 93] 0x0000000074982280           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00074368 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00031760
[ 94] 0x0000000005d5f9d6           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00391638 UIW_IsUserMessage+00000086
[ 95] 0x0000000005d60095           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00393365 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000117
[ 96] 0x0000000076ee87fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00165886 GetMenuBarInfo+00000638
[ 97] 0x0000000076ecf5fb                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00062971 SystemParametersInfoW+00000235
[ 98] 0x0000000076ed4895                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00084117 IsProcessDPIAware+00000465
[ 99] 0x00000000770111f5                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00332277 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000031
[100] 0x0000000076ed908a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00102538 PeekMessageW+00000186
[101] 0x0000000076ed50fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00086270 GetKeyState+00000238
[102] 0x0000000076ed3a6f                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00080495 PeekMessageA+00000087
[103] 0x0000000005d39a1b           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00236059 UIW_SetCurrentDialog+00000731
[104] 0x0000000005d61532           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00398642 ws_FreeSystemFont+00000482
[105] 0x0000000004308930 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00887088 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00055600
[106] 0x00000000043092f5 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00889589 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00058101
[107] 0x000000000430a100 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00893184 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00061696
[108] 0x00000000043128d2 C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00927954 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00001090
[109] 0x000000007498329d           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00078493 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00035885
[110] 0x0000000074983562           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00079202 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00036594
[111] 0x0000000074976915           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00026901 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00003781
[112] 0x0000000074979d52           C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00040274 mcr_invoke_on_interpreter_thread+00001602
[113] 0x0000000140005591        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00021905
[114] 0x0000000140005c3a        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00023610
[115] 0x0000000140006103        C:\Utils\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00024835
[116] 0x0000000076db59ed                   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll+00088557 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[117] 0x0000000076fec541                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00181569 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

I am processing a set of image; crashes do not seem related with high memory usage or the number of processed images. How may I approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to the issue: running Windows in Safe Mode causes matlab to crash less.